# How to enforce typing in gremlin/tinkerpop?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

In something like SQL, when I create a table I can create type constraints (String with certain lengths, booleans, etc).
How do I do that in gremlin? I am using a javascript implementation, and I know I can switch to typescript and add a lot of type enforcement on that side, but ideally I would also like to have type constraints on the database side too.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can switch to typescript and add a lot of type enforcement on that side

There is an open issue for Typescript at [TINKERPOP-2027](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2027) and while there was some activity there, no one has really picked up the work.

> I would also like to have type constraints on the database side too.

Constraints in the database are not a feature of TinkerPop. For 3.x we long ago committed to allowing graph providers who implement TinkerPop interfaces to provide their own functionality for doing so. There are a lot of historical reasons for that which I won't bother to detail, but the basic answer to your question is that if you want such functionality you need to choose a graph that has that sort of thing. Perhaps take a look at [JanusGraph](https://janusgraph.org/) or [DS Graph](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-graph) as both have a fairly robust schema language.